# How to stop login button functionality when email id is wrong using regular expression validator

Tags: c#, asp.net, authentication, membership

I am using `login control` in asp.net.
I am logging in using the email id instead username.
That is working fine.
I am checking for the email id by using the `<asp:RegularExpressionValidator />` control to validate the email id text box.
I given `ControlToValidate` property as id of the emailid text box.
When I click on login button, it is validating and showing error message `Email should be in correct format`.
But this is not stopping to login here.
It is trying to login with that wrong email id text box value and the password and saying `You are not register user` which should occur when user enters email id in correct format only.
In simple terms, the login control proceeding the

```
protected void Login1_Authenticate(object sender, AuthenticateEventArgs e)
```

event even though regular expression validator saying that email is not in correct format.

How to stop this login behaviour of the login control?

**Here is my regular expression:**

```
<asp:RegularExpressionValidator ID="emaildValidate" runat="server" 
     ErrorMessage="Email should be in correct format" 
     SetFocusOnError="True" ValidationExpression="\w+([-+.']\w+)*@\w+([-.]\w+)*\.\w+([-.]\w+)*"
     ControlToValidate="UserName" ValidationGroup="Login1">
</asp:RegularExpressionValidator>
```

**Button Html**

```
<asp:Button ID="LoginButton" CssClass="loginbutton" runat="server" CommandName="Login"
                                        Text="Sign In" ValidationGroup="Login1" OnClick="LoginButton_Click" />
```

Comment: can you put the html of `RegularExpressionValidator`

Comment: what is there in your `validation group`. Also can you put the html of your button.

Answer (score 2):

Here is login control for me and it works fine for me,check yours

```
<asp:Login ID="LoginUser" runat="server" EnableViewState="false" RenderOuterTable="false">
        <LayoutTemplate>
            <span class="failureNotification">
                <asp:Literal ID="FailureText" runat="server"></asp:Literal>
            </span>
            <asp:ValidationSummary ID="LoginUserValidationSummary" runat="server" CssClass="failureNotification" 
                 ValidationGroup="LoginUserValidationGroup"/>
            <div class="accountInfo">
                <fieldset class="login">
                    <legend>Account Information</legend>
                    <p>
                        <asp:Label ID="UserNameLabel" runat="server" AssociatedControlID="UserName">Email:</asp:Label>
                        <asp:TextBox ID="UserName" runat="server" CssClass="textEntry"></asp:TextBox>
                        <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="UserNameRequired" runat="server" ControlToValidate="UserName" 
                             CssClass="failureNotification" ErrorMessage="User Name is required." ToolTip="User Name is required." 
                             ValidationGroup="LoginUserValidationGroup">*</asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                             <asp:RegularExpressionValidator ID="emaildValidate" runat="server" 
     ErrorMessage="Email should be in correct format" 
     SetFocusOnError="True" ValidationExpression="\w+([-+.']\w+)*@\w+([-.]\w+)*\.\w+([-.]\w+)*"
     ControlToValidate="UserName" ValidationGroup="LoginUserValidationGroup">
</asp:RegularExpressionValidator>
                    </p>
                    <p>
                        <asp:Label ID="PasswordLabel" runat="server" AssociatedControlID="Password">Password:</asp:Label>
                        <asp:TextBox ID="Password" runat="server" CssClass="passwordEntry" TextMode="Password"></asp:TextBox>
                        <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="PasswordRequired" runat="server" ControlToValidate="Password" 
                             CssClass="failureNotification" ErrorMessage="Password is required." ToolTip="Password is required." 
                             ValidationGroup="LoginUserValidationGroup">*</asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                    </p>
                    <p>
                        <asp:CheckBox ID="RememberMe" runat="server"/>
                        <asp:Label ID="RememberMeLabel" runat="server" AssociatedControlID="RememberMe" CssClass="inline">Keep me logged in</asp:Label>
                    </p>
                </fieldset>
                <p class="submitButton">
                    <asp:Button ID="LoginButton" runat="server" CommandName="Login" Text="Log In" ValidationGroup="LoginUserValidationGroup"/>
                </p>
            </div>
        </LayoutTemplate>
    </asp:Login>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are mentioning that you are validate your `emailid` not `username` but in your required field validator you have

```
    ControlToValidate="UserName".
```

if your email text box  name is username then it's ok else validate the correct textbox.

Comment: Probably his username is an email form.

Comment: @Rahul... nope. I given correct value only. I changed the username to validate as a email id. If we didn't provide email id it will throw exception. Thats why I utilized the existing username for email id

Comment: @Mihir ok that's gud may you please put the code behind of login button.

Comment: @Mihir if u r using inbuild login control then ur button click event will be  "LoginUser_LoggingIn" here LoginUser is the name of the inbuild login control.just do one thing set breakpoint on that button click event and check that his click event is fired or not,if not then go to the events of inbuild login wizard and fire "LoggingIn" event and put your checking code under that.